# Scattering, absorption, emission and virtual photons

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, scattering, virtual-particles, non-linear-optics

From reading many questions on this site I have the following conclusions:

1. Interaction of a photon and a free electron is an instantaneous process of **scattering** (transfer of momentum) between said particles.
2. Interaction of a photon and an electron bound in atom is a very fast but not instantaneous (electron cloud has to restructure itself via resonant oscillation) process of **absorption** in which the photon is annihilated and atom ends up in excited state. Later another photon can be emitted from the atom taking away the excitation. This is *not* scattering as scattering happens for free electrons and absorption for bound.
3. **Virtual photons** (and other virtual particles) **don't exist** and are only a mathematical tool. Any view that they are "real virtual photons" is wrong.

Now to the questions:

1. I was told that spontaneous emissions is a stimulated emission, stimulated by a vacuum fluctuation photon coming from $ \frac{\hbar\omega}{2}$ in the photon field hamiltonian. How do I connect this with the fact that virtual photons don't exist?
2. In a process of second harmonic generation, are photons absorbed or scattered, as there is no real absorption? Is "virtual energy level" also only a mathematical tool? If so, why SHG is stronger if there is a real energy level nearby? How would SHG look on a Feynman diagram? How would it look on a Bloch sphere?